# Trying to understand this solution for a high-school coordinate geometry problem better

Tags: analytic-geometry

$\newcommand{\lrp}[1]{\left(#1\right)}$
The following is a high school level problem in coordinate geometry and the purpose of this post is to understand the solution better or discover other solutions or both.

> **Problem.**
> Show that all chords of the curve $3x^2 - y^2 - 2x + 4y = 0$ which subtend a right angle at the origin pass through a common point.

> **Solution.** Let $y = mx+c$ be the equation of a line not passing through the origin and which intersects the given curve at two points.
> Consider the algebraic expression
> $$
> 3x^2 - y^2 - (2x - 4y)\lrp{\frac{y-mx}{c}}
> $$
> which is an expression of the form $Ax^2 + 2Hxy + By^2$, its zero-set is either a pair of straight lines passing through the origin (possibly not distinct) or is just the origin (which happens if $H^2 < AB$).
> Further, if indeed the line $y=mx+c$ intersects the curve at two distinct points, then the zero-set of the above is necessarily the pair of of lines passing through the two points of intersection and through the origin.
> This is because the algebraic expression vanishes on both the points of intersection.
> These lines are perpendicular to each other if $A/B = -1$, since $A/B$ is the product of the slopes of the two lines.
> From here it is easy to show that all the lines $y = mx + c$ pass through a common point.

I understand this argument.
But the step where we created the algebraic expression was quite a clever one and it eludes me.

Is there a "deeper reason" as to where this came from?

Also, is there any other way to prove the same?
One may observe that the given curve is a hyperbola and then perhaps write down a 'hard' proof (as opposed to the 'soft' proof above).
But perhaps there are other such elegant or 'more natural' proofs.

Comment: One idea could be to switch over to projective coordinates $(x:y:z)$ and then eliminate $z$.

Comment: Do you think that showing the chords in question going through a common point (i.e., $\bf{\left(\text{1, -2}\right)}$) using methods available in coordinate geometry could be considered as a proof? By the way, the method I am talking about is a kind of layman’s attempt to solve this problem and by no means as chic as the solution you have given in your post.

Comment: @YNK I would consider what you describe a proof. If you think you can post it without much then please help us all learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x,y$ is one intersection point, then per orthogonality $(-y/z,x/z)$ is the second point for some $z\ne 0$. This second point satisfies the equations
$$
3y^2-x^2+2yz+4xz=0\\
x = -my+cz
$$
This might be confusing, so start again.

---

Let the second, orthogonal intersection point be $(x_2,y_2)=(-y,x)$. Then the primary intersection point has coordinates $(x_1,y_1)=(x/z,y/z)$ for some $z\ne 0$. Then this point satisfies the equations
$$
3x^2-y^2-2xz+4yz=0\\
y=mx+cz
$$
Elimination of $z$ gives the equation
$$
3x^2-y^2-2(x-2y)\frac{(y-mx)}{c}=0
$$
As this is now independent of $z$, this equation is true for all intersection points. To be valid for the claimed situation, the expanded equation $Ax^2+2Hxy+By^2=0$ has to be valid also for the second point, $Ay^2-2Hxy+Bx^2=0$, etc.

---

As the coefficients are independent of the point on the ellipse, the triple $(A,H,B)$ has to be proportional to $(-B,H,-A)$, which implies $A+B=0$. Or in full form without divisors
$$
0=[3c+2m]+[-c+4]=2(m+c+2)
$$
This means that the point $(x_3,y_3)=(1,-2)$ is on every such line.

Answer (score 2):

[image: HyperbolaChord]

$AB$ is one of the chord of the given curve $3x^2-y^2-2x+4y=0$, which subtends a right angle at the origin $O$. $OA$ and $OB$ are the line segments drawn from origin to the two points of intersection between the curve and the chord $AB$. We let the slope of $AB$ to be $\space m$. Since $\measuredangle AOB=90^o$, the slope of the line segment is equal to $\space -\dfrac{1}{m}$.

We start our proof by determining the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ in terms of $\space m\space$ as shown below.
$$3x_A^2-m^2x_A^2-2x_A+4mx_A=0\qquad\space\rightarrow\quad x_A=\dfrac{2-4m}{3-m^2}\qquad\rightarrow\quad y_A=\dfrac{2m-4m^2}{3-m^2}$$

$$3m^2x_B^2-x_B^2-2m^2x_B-4mx_B=0\quad\rightarrow\quad x_B=\dfrac{2m^2+4m}{3m^2-1}\quad\rightarrow\quad y_B=-\dfrac{2m+4}{3m^2-1}$$

Now, we can find the equation of the chord $AB$.
$$\dfrac{y-\dfrac{2m-4m^2}{3-m^2}}{x-\dfrac{2-4m}{3-m^2}}=\dfrac{y+\dfrac{2m+4}{3m^2-1}}{x-\dfrac{2m^2+4m}{3m^2-1}}$$

Simplification after cross multiplying leads to,
$$\left(1+4m-m^2\right)y+\left(6+2m-6m^2\right)x=4-6m-4m^2.$$

Our aim is to show that the line representing this equation passes through a certain point for all real values of $\space m$. If this particular point is $P\space\left(x_P,y_P\right)$, then we can express its $y-$coordinate as,
$$y_P=kx_P,$$
where $\space k\space$ is some  real constant, because both $x_P$ and $y_P$ are also real constants. Therefore, we have,
$$\left(1+4m-m^2\right)kx_P+\left(6+2m-6m^2\right)x_P=4-6m-4m^2.$$

Using this equation, It is possible to express $x_P$ in terms of the constant $\space k\space$ and the variable $\space m$.
$$x_P=\dfrac{4-6m-4m^2}{6+2m-6m^2+k\left(1+4m-m^2\right)}=\dfrac{4-6m-4m^2}{\left(6+k\right)+\left(2+4k\right)m-\left(6+k\right)m^2}$$

However, we need $x_P$ to be free of $\space m$, which is possible if and only if we could find a real constant $n\space$ such that,
$$n\left(4-6m-4m^2\right)= \left(6+k\right)+\left(2+4k\right)m-\left(6+k\right)m^2.$$

When we compare the coefficients of the first and the second terms of the left hand side with those of the right hand side, we get the following two equations,
$$4n=6+k\qquad\text{and}\qquad 6n=-2-4k.$$

$${\large{\bf{\therefore}}}\quad n=1,\quad k=-2,\quad x_P=1, \quad\text{and}\quad y_P=-2.$$

$\underline{\text{Additional}\enspace\text{Information}}$

If a chord of a hyperbola or an ellipse given by the equation $\space ax^2+by^2+cx+dy=0\space$ subtends a right angle at the origin, it passes through the point
$$\left(\dfrac{-c}{a+b},\space\dfrac{-d}{a+b}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the well-written answer.